# How to get loadbalancer reach instance's local service at 8080, AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, service, local, healthcheck

A very green networking person here; working in the AWS environment, and have the following:

- EC2 instance up and running; **I**
- AWS Classic loadbalancer (I guess ELB) up and running; **LB**
- **LB** includes **I**
- **LB** and **I** are in the same security group, that allows HTTP, SSH and HTTPS

There is a service at **I** running on http://172.13.30.130:8080.
I want the LB to healthcheck that service, and forward traffic to it.

What is the best way to do that? Port forwarding? How? Something else?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the type of load balancer you're using : ELB (legacy), ALB, or NLB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Creating a file; healthcheck.html ('OK' was the only content) which I added into the application's root folder of the .war file that was running on **I**.
2. I then opened up the spring-security filters of the application so that this URL would be exposed.
3. I also had to edit the web.xml for the application running on **I**.
4. I setup one security group for the **LB** that had "all traffic" for outbound", and "HTTPS:443", "HTTP:80" and "TCP:8080" as inbound.
5. I setup another security group for **I** that had "TCP:8080" (and "SSH:22")as inbound.
6. Finally I added the **I** to the **LB**, and verified that it picked up on the healthcheck alright.